# Media9 struggling with Polyglossia Arabic

Tags: packages, polyglossia, arabic, media9

Here is a minor problem met with Media9.

This plugin seems affected by the presence of arabic parameters, and erases all the text from the following Minimal not really working example :

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{media9}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}

\begin{document}

test

\begin{Arabic}
لاتنم
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

If Media9 is called after polyglossia, there is a message error (linked to the bidi package included inside polyglossia), but all the text is here, and files inserted with Media9 do also work.

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

test

\begin{Arabic}
لاتنم
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

I am interested by any explanation of this phenomenon.

Comment: I get an error with your first example as bidi uses a deprecated expl3 command.

Comment: After I replaced the deprecated commands with the new names the document compiled without problems.

Comment: Hi Ulrike,did you replace the new names in a .sty, or inside the main code ?

Comment: I replaced in the sty. Do you get an error with your first example? If yes it explains your failure and you should wait for a bidi update. Or get the newest version from the github.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help ! It should be ok now.